# GET 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, strongloop

Someone, being able to find me with the next error:

ionViewDidLoad VisualizarProfissionaisPage
GET http://localhost:3000/api/Profissionals/undefined 404 (Not Found) undefined

> This is where I will pull service from getId, passing the variable id

```
import { ListaEspecialidadesPage } from './../lista-especialidades/lista-especialidades';
    import { Especialidade } from './../../models/especialidade';
    import { ListaProfissionaisPage } from './../lista-profissionais/lista-profissionais';
    import { Profissional } from './../../models/profissional';
    import { ProfissionalServiceProvider } from './../../providers/profissionais-service';
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { EspecialidadeServiceProvider } from './../../providers/especialidade-service';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-visualizar-profissionais',
      templateUrl: 'visualizar-profissionais.html',
      providers: [ProfissionalServiceProvider, EspecialidadeServiceProvider]

    })
    export class VisualizarProfissionaisPage {
      public profissional: Profissional;
      public Titulo: string;
      id: number;
      listarProfissionais = ListaEspecialidadesPage;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                  public navParams: NavParams, 
                  public viewCtrl: ViewController,
                  public ProfissonalServiceProvider: ProfissionalServiceProvider,
                  public EspecialidadeServiceProvider: EspecialidadeServiceProvider) {
        this.Titulo = "Visualizar Profissionais";
        this.id = navParams.get('id');
        this.profissional = new Profissional(); 

      }
    ionViewDidLoad(){
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad VisualizarProfissionaisPage');
        this.ProfissonalServiceProvider.getId(this.id).subscribe(
            data => {this.profissional = data;},
            error => {console.log(error);}
          );
      }

    }
```

> This is where I will pull from the api:
>   This is ok, because if I put a number in the place of id, it takes the bank normally

```
import { HttpUtilService } from './http-util-service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Profissional } from './../models/profissional';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class ProfissionalServiceProvider {
   apiUrl ='http://localhost:3000/api';  

   constructor(public http: Http, public httpUtil: HttpUtilService) {
    console.log('Hello ProfissionalServiceProvider');
  }

  get (): Observable<Profissional> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/Profissionals')
     .map(res => res.json())
     .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json.error));
  }

  getId(id: number): Observable<Profissional> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/Profissionals/'+ id)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json.error)); 

}

}
```

If you can help me.

Comment: perhaps `this.id` is undefined when you call `this.ProfissonalServiceProvider.getId(this.id)` - can't see in your code where `id` is undefined, which indicates that `navParams.get('id')` returns undefined in `this.id = navParams.get('id');` ... can't see in your code where a param called `id` is set for `VisualizarProfissionaisPage` constructor ... in fact, can't see anywhere in the code you posted that even refers to `VisualizarProfissionaisPage` class at all

Comment: May be you should move `this.id = navParams.get('id');` to the `ionViewDidLoad()`?

Comment: I already tried to take the "ionViewDidLoad()", did not work.

Comment: Where is the API located? On node?